# Accessing JBoss 5 EJB3.0 from JBoss 7.1 EJB3.1

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I have a bunch of services (EJBs, remotem stateless) running on JB-AS 5.1.0. Now I have a new AS7.1 on which I develop new Services (JEE6, EJB, CDI, ...)
I want to access the AS5.1 Services via remote JNDI.

Has anyone done this before and can help? I need my JEE6-Beans to have access to the AS5.1 client-jars, so I am trying to add them to ear/lib or create a module containing the jars, but so far without luck ...

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions I have seen so far can be found [here](http://wolf-71.blogspot.com/2010/02/et-phone-home.html). You can follow [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/623404) forum for more information.

Please post your findings here so others can help / benefit.

Good luck!